# How to scroll a invisible element in the picker using xamarin ui test?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0, xamarin.uitest

I'm using the Xamarin UI Test with NUint3, I'm trying to test a number picker to scroll to the next available text where the elements are invisible.

Example:

### I have a picker with Text1, Text2, and Text3.

When I open the Picker it always shows Text1.

---

When I tried to scroll to Text2, my element of text2 is invisible so I tried to scroll using below codes:

---

- App.Tap(query => query.All().Marked("Text2"));
- App.DoubleTapCoordinates(item.Rect.CenterX, item.Rect.CenterY + 20);
- App.Query(x => x.Text("Text2")).FirstOrDefault();

None of these worked to scroll to next element. So, please do help me if there is any way in which i can scroll or move to next text.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Text2` element is invisible, that means it is not in the "Tree".

> The tree is the hierarchical list of the views that are visible on the screen

If an item is not in the tree, you will not be able to perform your Automated UITesting functions.

Here's how you see what is in the [Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-repl?tabs=vswin#discovering-views-with-the-tree-command).

Comment: Sameer, Thanks for the input, but if there are hidden elements in the tree also can be invoked some time as picker mainly supports hidden elements only so, maybe by any other way if we can scroll to that element or drag to that text would help me a lot.

Comment: Yeah could you please share a picture/text of your tree so I can take a look to see if that’s the case